# Django model choice field exclude value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

this is a example a model choice:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
   )
```

forms.py :

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Student.objects.exclude(year_in_school='Freshman')
```

how can filter the choices for example exclude 'Freshman' from the list on the forms.py?

Comment: You have a typo in `Student.objects.exlude(year_in_school='Freshman')` -> Should be `Student.objects.exclude(year_in_school='Freshman')`

Comment: i try but does work, thnx